# Detecting an image on the screen using applescript

Tags: applescript

How could I detect an image on the screen and then act on that detection? For example, if I was running the script (applescript), and looked for the stackoverflow icon and loaded this page, the program would show an alert, then pause the program for 5 seconds, then go back to the original detect image script.

Comment: Applescript does not have anything built in to do this. You would need to use another, command-line, app that does image recognition. Maybe there is a way to bypass using images. ie check what application is running and perhaps what page/document that app is displaying and acting on that. Applescript can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) - vanilla AppleScript does not know anything about low level stuff like images or screens.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can't do this with applescript. However an alternative might be to detect something on the web page itself. For example if you wanted to detect the stack overflow image at the top of this page you could do that. You wouldn't actually detect the image but you could detect the image name (or path). That's in the html code of the page, so you could check the web page code and check that text for the appropriate image name or path.

The applescript part about having an applescript to perform a task periodically is easy. You just write a stay-open applescript application that performs your task every few seconds. Then a simple variable which turns true for a successful detection would serve as a switch to make the delay happen.